# push to a git branch only if the remote branch already exists

Tags: git

I have an automated system which conditionally makes commits and pushes to a pull requested branch

The workflow looks something like this:

1. User makes pull request
2. Automated system checks out pull request
3. (if changes) Automated system makes commit
4. (if changes) Automated system pushes to pull request branch

The problem with this is there's a race between Step 1 and Step 4 where the user *deletes* their branch.

In this situation, step 4 will *create* a branch

What I'd like to do is only push to the branch if it exists.  Checking if the branch exists before pushing is a non-solution as it cannot be done in an atomic step (it reduces the race condition but does not eliminate it)

If it helps, the pushes are always expected to be fast-forward and are currently being pushed via `git push --quiet remotename HEAD`

Is there an option to `git push` which would prevent branch creation in this situation?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to fetch all the remote branches and then check with a script if the branch you are considering pushing exists, shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: @Michael please read carefully: **Checking if the branch exists before pushing is a non-solution as it cannot be done in an atomic step (it reduces the race condition but does not eliminate it)**

Comment: @AnthonySottile I'm sure it cannot be done **atomically** at the client side. It can be done at the server side with `pre-receive` or [`update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#update) hooks.

Comment: @AnthonySottile: I'm also not sure about that atomicity of a push is what you're heading for, however, not creating the remote branch on push is possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--force-with-lease` option allows you to perform a conditional push

The pipeline essentially becomes:

```sh
orig_commit=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

# perform side-effects + commits ...

git push remotename HEAD "--force-with-lease=branchname:${orig_commit}"
```

when the remote branch is deleted it produces an error message and exits nonzero:

```
$ git push origin HEAD --force-with-lease=branchname:21bd2ef3e67adf7b8a5fc56a7e26a2a25589f346
To github.com:asottile/astpretty
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> branchname (stale info)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:asottile/astpretty'
```

when the remote branch exists at the previous revision:

```
$ git push origin HEAD --force-with-lease=branchname:21bd2ef3e67adf7b8a5fc56a7e26a2a25589f346
Enumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 183 bytes | 183.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:asottile/astpretty
   21bd2ef..77bcec3  HEAD -> branchname
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an option to `git push` which would prevent branch creation in this situation?

Yes, `git push remotename :`

> The special refspec : directs Git to push "matching" branches: for every branch that exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote side.

(from: `git push --help` / https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

I read you're looking for atomic pushes, maybe the `git push` `--atomic` option is also of your interest.

Comment: this doesn't work for 2 reasons (1) it pushes branches unrelated to the target branch (2) it does not indicate whether it was successful or not

Comment: (1) make a temporary local clone just for the push with the branch in question if removing any other branch is not an option.  (2) it does. if the push fails it tells  (e.g. connection or authentication error) by exit status. Pushes are reported on standard output, the successful push not creating the remote branch gives the up-to-date message, the successful push updating the remote branch shows that and which branch has been updated from/to what (see git-push for the meaning of the output, it's documented). to decide between those two cases is _trivial_ in a single branch scenario.

Comment: I just tried it and it says only "Everything up to date" with exit code 0

Comment: This means there was no update necessary. Either the remote branch was deleted (so there is nothing to push and everything is up to date) or the remote branch was already updated (so there is nothing to push and everything is up to date). Following your original description you have to check the repository if it added a new commit. If that is the case, the remote branch was deleted as otherwise you would have seen the branch updated in the output instead.

Comment: yeah sorry but parsing an english message from stdout isn't acceptable for scripting.  I found a better way -- I guess I'll self answer

Comment: Oh, don't feel sorry, as commented, the output acceptable for scripting is documented in the manpage. Can't wait to see what you found out.